# How to change operating system cursor with electron

Tags: electron

Is it possible to change the operating system cursor with Electronjs?

When I use `startDrag`, for example, the cursor in macOS is the same as `html` drag; I wish to change that cursor to a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

### provide an icon

If you're talking about the `event.sender.startDrag` method that exists on incoming IPC messages in the main thread, then you can provide an `icon` property to that method's argument, like so:

```js
event.sender.startDrag({
  file: absPathToFileBeingDragged,
  icon: DROP_ICON_PATH
})
```

Note that the [Electron docs for `startDrag`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsstartdragitem) say MacOS *requires* that you provide an icon. The docs also say `icon` can be a path to an image or an instance of `NativeImage` (which I assume means you can generate a bitmap in RAM and pass its handle without writing that bitmap to disk first).

In context, this might look like:

```js
const DROP_ICON_PATH = Path.join(__dirname, 'custom-drag-out-icon.png')

ipcMain.on('drag-file-out-of-app', ( event, ...dataFromCaller ) => {
  // ...do some work to locate or create the file the user will be dragging
  
  event.sender.startDrag({
    file: absPathOfFileToBeDragged,
    icon: DROP_ICON_PATH
  })
})
```

<sup>The above code is lightly modified for clarity from the tutorial on [this page](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/native-file-drag-drop).</sup>

Comment: thank you for your detailed response, I tried that a while back and it changes the file-icon but not the cursor icon/image sadly, I remember checking the code of electron and it seems it is not possible through the API.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I think Electron does let you use a custom cursor (have never done it myself but have glanced at the docs), but I assume the cursor returns to OS default when it exits your app's footprint.